# Change of title without editing history

Tags: support, editing

I was looking at the list of hot questions and I saw this:

[image: Question title is - "Are all paedophiles to this sequence of the form p to the k with p prime?"]

Thinking someone was trolling, I clicked on the question, only to find that the offending word had changed to 'pseudoprime':

[image: Question title now reads - "Are all pseudoprimes to this sequence of the form p to the k with p prime?"]

There was no edit history or record of anything being changed.  I clicked back to check I hadn't misread it, but no - the question was just as I had remembered.

Shortly afterwards, I looked again, and the title *had* been corrected to 'pseudoprimes'.  But there was still no record of the question having been edited.

What is going on here?

Comment: Could a benign explanation code be the Question was posted from a smartphone and afflicted by [autocorrect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrection)?.

Comment: [It happens a lot, you know.](http://www.damnyouautocorrect.com/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is presumably due to the 5 minute* grace period: If you write a post and edit it within 5 minutes, the edits do not show up in the revision history - it is as if the post had never been edited. This also applies after you make an edit on a post and then make another one quickly afterwards.

(*For detail on the current functionality, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216567/reset-question-grace-period-once-an-answer-has-been-posted/251876#251876). It's a little more complicated than a strict 5 minute limit)